# How can we know which Thread is used to execute Task?

Tags: ios, swift

All the while, I thought non-Main thread is used to execute Task

But, the simple code snippet shows I was wrong

```
import UIKit

class X {
    static let INSTANCE = X()
    
    private init() {
        print(">>>> X: outside Task, thread is \(Thread.isMainThread)")
        Task {
            print(">>>> X: inside Task, thread is \(Thread.isMainThread)")
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        _ = X.INSTANCE
        
        print(">>>> ViewController: outside Task, thread is \(Thread.isMainThread)")
        Task {
            print(">>>> ViewController: inside Task, thread is \(Thread.isMainThread)")
        }
    }
}
```

The following is printed

```
>>>> X: outside Task, thread is true
>>>> ViewController: outside Task, thread is true
>>>> X: inside Task, thread is false
>>>> ViewController: inside Task, thread is true
```

It shows either Main thread, or non-Main thread can be used to execute Task.

How does the system decide which thread is used to execute Task? I do not understand for the above example.

Before executing Task, both `ViewController` and `X` are running in Main thread.

But why

1. Task in `ViewController` is executed in Main thread.
2. Task in `X` is executed in non-Main thread.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) is marked `@MainActor` which means that tasks will be dispatched on the main thread. Your `X` class is not marked `@MainActor` so tasks are dispatched on any available thread.